# Basic UJS AJAX Rails 3.0 Update Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Very simple AJAX call to make a div go up. Though it's not working. Trying to transition from 2.3.8 to 3.0. Any help is greatly appreciated. I've googled, though I'm not able to make any sense of the jargon. :( Thanks in advance

View:

```
<div class="test">
  Whompa
</div>
<%= link_to 'Blind-Up', :controller=>:home,:actions=>:test, :remote =>true %>
```

Controller:

```
  def test
    render :update do |page|
      page[:test].visual_effect :blind_up
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great Post on an example of using Rails3 + CRUD + UJS.

http://www.stjhimy.com/posts/7

Answer (score 0):

For Posterity,

I think the answer to this is that the JS methodologies of Rails 3 are significantly different from those of 2.x

Looking to write UJS using JQuery,  I might suggest this:

View:

```
<div class="slide_toggle">
  Whompa
</div>
```

some_js_file.js:

```
$('div.slide_toggle').after('<a class="toggle_link" href="#">Slide Up</a>'); //since the link is only good if there's JS to begin with, add it in your JS instead of on the page.
$('a.toggle_link').live('click', function(event) {
  this.closest().slideToggle();
}
```